# Build MXNET library for R

Tags: r, build, mxnet

I have used R and MXNET and I see that the version of MXNET from the repo is 0.7

I've built 0.93 from Git and I succeded. (adding lots of dependencies and missing libraries.

But the thing is that it did not create "mxnet.dll" for R

The only output I get is "libmxnet.dll" and R is not loading it. I believe the old mxnet.dll is not going to work with the new libmxnet.dll

Comment: I have upload the 0.9.4 for CPU. Please try it.

Comment: How do I get this new version? God it's been a month I suspect I did replied but haven't got anything back and now I see there was no reply

Comment: 0.9.4 has been uploaded into drat repo a month ago.

Comment: downloading. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have provided the CPU and GPU pkgs for Windows.

For CPU-only pkg:

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet")
```

For GPU-enable pkg:

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/GPU"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet")
```

Comment: Thanks! I have just downloaded R 3.4.0 and updated the package (two days ago). Why there are no binaries for GPU? It is really annoying to compile all the stuff to make a GPU version (too many pre-requisites). Maybe that's why. But for a final user is painful

Comment: @David Actually there is GPU package for R 3.4.0. try  `install.packages("mxnet", repos="http://104.131.145.31")`

Comment: @David We are evaluating the correct place to host the GPU pkg for Windows. Your opinion will be appreciated: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/6543

Comment: THANKS! that's much better... I stopped today at the point where you must add the include files. I don't know about the GPU package I'm not someone who can give an opinion. Maybe a different package name? like mxnet_gpu (or something with chars available to name packages. Isn't the GPU package also CPU-able?

Comment: I could not successfully install the GPU package. I've deployed a fresh R copy (3.4.0) in a Windows 7x64 computer and then ran `install.packages("drat"), drat::addRepo("dmlc"), install.packages("mxnet", repos="http://104.131.145.31")`. It downloaded  187.6MB, warned of missing dependencies which I installed later and then reinstalled mxnet. No luck. `require(mxnet)` results in `Loading required package: mxnet
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘mxnet’`

Comment: @David Can you open an issue on github?

Comment: I don't see updates here but I see there were updates on GitHub. Will look at that on Monday. Thanks!